# How to replace the contents of an integer array with the index value at each index?

Tags: c#

How do I replace the contents of an array of integers so that the value at each index is the index itself?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var result = array;
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array.IndexOf(i);
    Console.WriteLine(array.IndexOf(i));
}
return result;
```

Given an input array `(0, 0 ,0)`, I am getting the following console output: `0 -1 -1`.  And the array output contents are `(0, 0, 0)` instead of `(0, 1, 2)`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is a bit confusing. But if you mean how to assign the index value to the arrays elements you could do this.

```
var result = array;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        Console.WriteLine(array.IndexOf(i));
    }
    return result;
```

The result will then be 0,1,2

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion, thank you it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should help.

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for(int i = 0; i < myIntArray.Length; i++)
    {
        myIntArray[i] = i; 
        Console.WriteLine(myIntArray[i]);
    }
```

correct me if i am wrong.